# Fasting on Erev Shabbos/Yom Tov

Tags: halacha, shabbat, yom-tov, fast-days

Is it permitted to fast on Erev Shabbos or Erev Yom Tov? I've heard about people taking on fasts until chatzos, but no later. What is the halacha on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=28

Per Orach Chaim 249:3 "Anshei maaseh would fast every Erev Shabbos". However the Beer Heteiv brings the Bach that it is prohibited.